# Fetch first weekday and last weekday from table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a schedule table in mysql. I want to fetch first day and last day of the table as per country code.

Table

| COUNTRY_CODE | IS_WORKING | FROM_TIME | END_TIME | DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IN | **no** | **NULL** | **NULL** | Sunday |
| IN | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Monday |
| IN | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Tuesday |
| IN | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Wednesday |
| IN | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Thursday |
| IN | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Friday |
| IN | **no** | **NULL** | **NULL** | Saturday |
| UAE | yes | 10:00:00 | 19:00:00 | Sunday |
| UAE | yes | 10:00:00 | 19:00:00 | Monday |
| UAE | yes | 10:00:00 | 19:00:00 | Tuesday |
| UAE | yes | 10:00:00 | 19:00:00 | Wednesday |
| UAE | yes | 10:00:00 | 19:00:00 | Thursday |
| UAE | **no** | **NULL** | **NULL** | Friday |
| UAE | **no** | **NULL** | **NULL** | Saturday |
| UK | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Sunday |
| UK | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Monday |
| UK | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Tuesday |
| UK | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Wednesday |
| UK | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Thursday |
| UK | yes | 09:00:00 | 18:00:00 | Friday |
| UK | **no** | **NULL** | **NULL** | Saturday |

I want result as per below :

| COUNTRY_CODE | START_WORKING_DAY | END_WORKING_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IN | Monday | Friday |
| UAE | Sunday | Thursday |
| UK | Sunday | Friday |

Comment: Is there any column which can represent the order? How to defind your `START_WORKING_DAY` and `END_WORKING_DAY` each counrty code

Comment: sorry but this table design is a nightmare. You should get rid of this 3 columns and use 2 date time columns for start and and. Then you can calculate everything you want

Comment: LAG() IS NULL for starting day and LEAD() IS NULL for finishing day. Formally weekdays may be in the middle of the week, so you must use 2 copies of the rows building 2-week table (order by weekday number + 7 * copy number) and check working days after first and before last weekday.

Comment: @Thallius but this data has no dates

Comment: @Akina I think you are reading in requirements that are not there

Comment: @ysth I see sample data and desired output for them. I see "task definition" (too short) in the question. I recommend how to solve this (including the case when NULL is, for example, in the row 'Wednesday' for some country). And I cannot understand where you have found the contradiction. I see that schedule table does not contain definite dates.

Comment: @Akina say just Saturday and Sunday are set; by the simple meaning I read, Sunday is the earliest day and Saturday is the latest day, regardless of the gap between them.  I think you are saying to detect the gap and say it's a 2 day work week starting Saturday and ending Sunday.

Comment: @ysth No. The condition "check working days after first and before last weekday" discards starting and finishing partial working days ranges and produces the output by complete week data only.

Comment: @Akina I didn't follow that at all.  See my answer for how I'm reading the question

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simply:

```
select COUNTRY_CODE, 
   dayname(min(str_to_date(concat(197001,DAY),"%X%V%W"))) start_working_day,
   dayname(max(str_to_date(concat(197001,DAY),"%X%V%W"))) end_working_day
from test
where IS_WORKING="yes"
group by 1
```

Comment: That's very neat combining `DAY` with a supplementary year_month value to make it calculable. Besides, it's MySQL version-neutral to begin with. Thank you both for sharing.

Comment: @blabla_bingo it's actually a supplementary year and week number

Comment: @ysth Thank you for correcting me.  This is a fine use of functions in datetime calculations. I have learned a lot from you.